# Changing scale of pseudo-element slightly moves the parent element

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, next.js, bulma

I made a project with just the important code: [git](https://gitlab.com/pakleni/css-jitter)

You can see it on the navbar buttons [here](https://css-jitter.vercel.app/)(live website of the git project).

This css also changes the color of the moved text on some browsers (friends chrome, but not on mine). Have no clue how to fix it.

```css
.underline {
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.35s ease;
}

.underline::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  bottom: 30%;
  left: 0;
  background-color: white;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.underline:hover::before {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0.9);
  transform: scaleX(0.9);
}

nav {
  height: 100px;
}

.navbar-item {
  font-size: 25pt;
}
```

```html
<nav className="navbar">
  <div className="navbar-brand">
    <Link href="/">
    <a className="navbar-item">
      <img src="/trinity-logo.png" />
    </a>
    </Link>
  </div>

  <div className="navbar-menu">
    <div className="navbar-start">
      <Link href="/">
      <a className="navbar-item underline">
        <b>Hover</b>
      </a>
      </Link>
      <Link href="/">
      <a className="navbar-item underline">
        <b>Hover</b>
      </a>
      </Link>
      <Link href="/">
      <a className="navbar-item underline">
        <b>Hover</b>
      </a>
      </Link>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

those navbar classes are from Bulma(I can't paste all of that css here).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please include your HTML here. CSS is only half of what we need. You should also post the rendered/compiled CSS, not the SASS. Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I edited my submission with better reproducible example.

Comment: You need to add the code to the question, not an offsite link. If any of those offsite links become invalid, or in the case of your website become fixed, this question will be useless to future visitors.

Comment: i decided to leave a git repository up with everything needed to reproduce the bug. But here is the important bit of code without Bulma